# what is actually "EXTENT" in gis slang?

Tags: gis, conventions, openlayers, esri, mapserver

I am not clearly understanding the extent parameter in GIS applications.
for ex, In mapserver map file we are using

```
NAME "CGI-CONTEXT-DEMO"
STATUS ON
SIZE 400 300
**EXTENT -2200000 -712631 3072800 3840000**
UNITS METERS
IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
IMAGETYPE png
```

here extent means lower left x,y and upper right x,y.
but long,lat values are not used here , then what is this value? How it is arrived?

Comment: Maybe a question to take to http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Thqr - I wish there was a way to migrate questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extent is simply an area(square) which is specified with left lower and right upper x and y. In your example it doesn't look like lon lat because it's just a different coordinate system.

Comment: diff co-ordinate system means instead of lat, long what is to be used?

Comment: While lon/lat is measered in degrees, in example above it's for sure meters. Probably somewhere in Mapserver file you find something like EPSG:4326. That tells you what coordinate system it is.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum bounding rectangle (xmin, ymin and xmax, ymax) defined by coordinate pairs of a data source. All coordinates for the data source fall within this boundary.

Source: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/extent (GIS dictionary)